# Changing the FROM email address in Outlook 2007 AD HOC i.e. spoofing the FROM address

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a web-only-based email address I use, and want to write FROM it within Outlook 2007.

I cannot smpt though it, my web-based email provider does not provide that.

In Outlook, I can configure an account that has my web-based email address as the REPLY-TO address, HOWEVER Outlook still sends the email FROM whichever SMTP server I send it through.

So effectively I cannot send an email from within Outlook 2007 that really appears to be sent from my web-based email address.

But I want to.

I can manually invoke/display the "FROM" field, and enter my web-based email address there, however Outlook appears to ignore that and still list the smtp account email address as the FROM address once the email is sent

I have searched on the web for this, and have found nothing.

I am running XP and Outlook freestanding i.e. without Exchange.

Thanks!!

---

Added clarification:

Thanks ppumpkin - it's not so much that I want to spoof anything...

I used to be a Eudora Pro user, and Eudora happily sent emails via any legit smtp server (with my appropriate login credentials) WHILE listing the From address as anything I chose. In other words, it did not differentiate between the Reply-To and the From address.

However, Outlook does. While Outlook happily accepts any Reply-To email address I put into the account settings, it appears to stubbornly insist on the From address being whatever smtp server I sent it through.

Does this make enough sense and/or change your kind answer?

Thanks again!

Comment: "Spoofing" is done at server level, not client level. So you will either need a proxy SMTP server/script to do this. Outlook is dumb and for general public, imagine each john doe having the ability to "spoof" emails.. bladdy nightmare.. Whatever it is you want to do it should be done via some SMTP (postfix/sendmail) or winblows based email senders... Soz..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ppumpkin - it's not so much that I want to spoof anything...

I used to be a Eudora Pro user, and Eudora happily sent emails via any legit smtp server (with my appropriate login credentials) WHILE listing the From address as anything I chose. In other words, it did not differentiate between the Reply-To and the From address.

However, Outlook does. While Outlook happily accepts any Reply-To email address I put into the account settings, it appears to stubbornly insist on the From address being whatever smtp server I sent it through.

Does this make enough sense and/or change your kind answer?

Thanks again!